# How do I build a function that transforms the columns entered from the DataTable to xml?

Tags: c#, xml, datatable

There is no problem in converting static columns to xml
The problem is that I'm trying to make the conversion through an array and insert it as I need it every time
can you add
loop to XElement

```
  string  creatColumnXml(params int[] ColId)
        {
            
            return new XElement(table.TableName, table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row =>
                 new XElement("row",
                         //for ( int i =0;i<ColId.Length;i++)
                         //new XElement(table.Columns[ColId[i]].ColumnName, row[ColId[i]]),
                         new XElement(table.Columns[0].ColumnName, row[0]),
                         new XElement(table.Columns[1].ColumnName, row[1]),
                          new XElement(table.Columns[2].ColumnName, row[2])

                 ))
            ).ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Didn’t get your question? Do you want to run a for loop for table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ again within your existing lambda

```cs
string creatColumnXml(params int[] ColId)
{
    return new XElement(table.TableName,
        table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row =>
            new XElement("row",
                ColId.Select(c => new XElement(table.Columns[c].ColumnName, row[c]))
            )
        ).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
 XElement[] c = new XElement[ColId.Length];
            XElement[] r = new XElement[table.Rows.Count];
            int y = 0;
            string s="" ;
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
            
                for (int i = 0; i < ColId.Length; i++)
                {
                    c[i] = new XElement(table.Columns[ColId[i]].ColumnName, row[ColId[i]]);
                }     
                r[y] = new XElement("row",c);
                y++;
            }
            s = new XElement(table.TableName, r).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you got your DataRows from a DataSet, you can just directly convert the DataSet to XML using the DataSet.WriteXml method.

Here's an example, hope this is helpful.

```
    DataSet MainDS = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand( "select name, city, country from user" );
    da.Fill(MainDS, "row");

    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        try {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            settings.CheckCharacters = false;
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings)) {
                MainDS.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
                xmlWriter.Close();
            }
            ms.Position = 0;
            xml.Load(ms);
        } catch (Exception err) {
            throw new Exception("Error loading dataset to xml", err);
        }
    }
```

From there, use XSL to format.

You can also direct .NET to create attribute based XML.

```
foreach (System.Data.DataTable dt in ds.Tables) {
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns) {
        dc.ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
    }
}
```